# How do I use gets when running a file from the terminal?

Tags: ruby, command-line, gets

I'm trying to execute this program from the command line, and I'm not able to use `gets.chomp`, instead, it returns the key value.

I am entering: `ruby name_of_file.rb name_of_file.txt`

```
def caesar_cipher(key)
  s = gets.chomp
  encoded = ""

  s.each_byte do |l|
    if ((l >= 65 && l <= 90) || (l >= 97 && l <= 122))
      encoded += (l+key).chr
    else
      encoded += l.chr
    end
  end
  encoded
end

File.readlines(ARGV[0]).map(&:to_i).each {|key| puts caesar_cipher(key)}
```

I know the program does not execute the caesar cipher completely, I am just trying to figure out how to run it from the command line without having to use pry or irb.

Comment: What happens when you run the program from the command line?

Comment: It prints the key value. So if the txt file has a line containing the number 3, it prints 3.

Answer (score 1):

You want to manually enter the cipher key?

Use `STDIN.gets`

Comment: Thank you! So if you're running a program from irc or pry you can use regular gets.chomp, but when you're running from the command line have to use STDIN?

Comment: Or `$stdin` instead of STDIN. At the start of a program's run, they're the same, but you can quietly change `$stdin` to something else if you want. Changing `STDIN` to something else will get the "already initialized constant" warning.

Comment: It is common to change `$stdin` temporarily, when you need input from another pipe.  When you are done with that need, reassign `$stdin` back to STDIN.  This is true for the pipes.  Perhaps read a little bit about the common streams we use every day... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams and the Ruby open3 class in STDLIB at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html

Comment: @EMK428: No, you don't have to use `STDIN.gets` when running from the command line. You can use `Kernel#gets` just fine. `Kernel#gets` will read the contents of the file you are passing as argument (in this case `name_of_file.txt`), just like its documentation says it does. If you don't want to read that file, *then* you need to explicitly read from the terminal; but that's because of a choice *you* made, not because you are running from the terminal vs from IRb.

Answer (score 1):

@vgoff has the answer, but here's how I'd rewrite the the code to be more readable:

```
def caesar_cipher(key)

  encoded = ""

  s = STDIN.gets.chomp

  s.each_char do |l|
    case l
    when 'A' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'z'
      encoded += (l.ord + key).chr
    else
      encoded += l
    end
  end

  encoded

end

# File.readlines(ARGV[0]).map(&:to_i).each {|key| puts caesar_cipher(key)}
puts caesar_cipher(0)
puts caesar_cipher(1)
```

Instead of splitting characters into bytes, I'd probably use `each_char` to maintain the character-encoding. I'd use a `case` statement to let me use two ranges to define upper and lower-case characters cleanly, and use `ord` to get the actual ordinal value for a character, instead of the byte.

It's more readable, but might not fully satisfy your needs.